# Plotmodel to XPS via OxyPlot C#

Tags: c#, plot, xps, oxyplot

I'm currently facing a problem with printing a Plotmodel to an XPS-File. 

What I have so far:

---

```
/// <summary>
/// Plotmodel to XPS-File
/// </summary>
/// <param name="model">The model</param>
/// <param name="fileName">The fileName</param>
/// <param name="width">Width of the model</param>
/// <param name="height">Height of the model</param>
public void Export(PlotModel model, string fileName, double width, double height)
{
   try
   {
      using (Package xpsPackage = Package.Open(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
      {
        using (var doc = new XpsDocument(xpsPackage))
        {
            var g = new Grid();

            var p = new OxyPlot.Wpf.Plot { Model = model }; //Problem?
            g.Children.Add(p);

            var size = new Size(width, height);
            g.Measure(size);
            g.Arrange(new Rect(size));
            g.UpdateLayout();


            if (xpsdw == null) //XpsDocumentWriter xpsdw
                xpsdw = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);
            }
            if (xpsdw != null)
            {
                xpsdw.Write(g);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This Code works fine (once), but the Problem is: No matter how often you use this method, you will always have just one Page with data. So if you want to print a second Plotmodel into the XPS-File the old one is deleted and you can only see the new one.

So the Question is: 
*Do you have an idea, how to append the new Plotmodel to the old XPS-File without overwriting it?*

I also tried to use:

```
XpsExporter.Export(model, fileName, width, height);
```

instead of my function, but this didn't worked either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know in advance that you will be writing multiple plots to a single file, you should look into [VisualsToXpsDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.visualstoxpsdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you truly must append additional pages to an existing document on disk, it will be more difficult. You will need to dig down through the existing document to get to a `FixedDocument` (a child of the `FixedDocumentSequence`). Once you have the `FixedDocument`, you can add a new `PageContent` object to it. There is an example near the bottom of [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5345f4f2-0d1e-4b05-824a-add23000dc46/i-need-to-add-page-to-xps-document?forum=windowsxps).

Comment: This first Tipp looks nice, but how can I change my Plotmodel into a Visual?

Comment: @user3173210 I'm not familiar with plotmodel, but if you can add it to a grid, it most likely inherits from visual. If not, try passing in the parent grid instead

Comment: It is working now. Passing the grid instead of the Plotmodel was a good Idea. Thx!